# Question on derivation of equations for a viscously damped vibrating beam

Tags: classical-mechanics, vibrations

I'm trying to work through and understand the derivation for the solution of a vibrating beam that also has viscous damping.  I'm using the following book:

Rao, Singiresu S. "Vibration of Continuous Systems", Wiley and Sons (2007), ISBN 978-0-471-77171-5.

**Background**

The dynamic equation for a vibrating Euler-Bernoulli beam is the following:

$$\rho A(x)\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial t^2} + c(x)\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left( EI(x) \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} \right) = f(x,t)$$

$\rho$ is the density of the beam, $A(x)$ is the cross-sectional area, $w(x,t)$ is the transverse deflection of the beam, $c(x)$ is some type viscous resistance, $E$ is the Young's modulus of the beam, $I(x)$ is the 2nd moment of area, and $f(x,t)$ is an external transverse force on the beam. Boundary conditions are whichever are appropriate at each end: fixed, free, simply supported, etc.  The choice of BC's affect the actual functional form of the modes, but it isn't really important to this question.

For the non-homogeneous equation above, the solution is found by first solving the homogeneous equation to get the vibrational modes for the free vibration problem, and using those orthogonal modes as a basis for solving the non-homogeneous equation.

We assume a solution of the following form:

$$w(x,t) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\phi_i(x)\eta_i(t)$$

where $\phi_i(x)$ are the modes to the free vibration with the same BCs, and are orthogonal to each other and normalized such that:

$$\int_0^L{\rho A(x) \phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)}dx= \delta_{ij}; \qquad \delta_{ij}= \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad i\neq j \\
            1 & \quad i=j
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kroeneker delta. Substituting the assumed form for $w(x,t)$ into the original equation, multiplying both sides by $\phi_j$ and integrating from $0$ to $L$ allows simplification by applying the orthogonality condition.  The simplified form is:

$$\frac{d^2\eta_i}{dt^2}+\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_{ij} \frac{d\eta_i}{dt} + {\omega_i}^2\eta_i=Q_i$$

where $\omega_i$ is the $i$th natural frequency, and

$$c_{ij}=\int_0^L{c(x)\phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)}dx $$
$$ Q_i=\int_0^L{f(x,t)\phi_i(x)}dx $$

The method of dealing with the $c_{ij}$ terms such that we can apply orthogonality and reduce it to a series of uncoupled ODEs is in pg 169-171 of  Rao's book.  In this case he uses a more generic form of the vibration equation to include multidimensional problems:

$$ M(\underline{\mathbf{X}}) \frac{\partial^2 w(\underline{\mathbf{X}},t)}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}C[w(\underline{\mathbf{X}},t)] + L[w(\underline{\mathbf{X}})]=f(\underline{\mathbf{X}},t)$$

where $M$ is the mass function, $C$ is a generic linear operator for viscous damping, and $L$ is a generalized linear operator, so that in this specific case $M(\underline{\mathbf{X}})=\rho A(x)$, $C[w(\underline{\mathbf{X}},t)]=c(x)w(x,t)$, and $L[w(\underline{\mathbf{X}})]=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left( EI(x) \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} \right)$.

On page 171, Rao says the following:

> In many practical situations, the viscous damping operator $C$ is not known. To simplify the analysis, the operator $C$ is assumed to be a linear combination of the operator $L$ and the mass function $M$:
>
> $$ C=\alpha_1 L + \alpha_2 M $$
>
> where $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are constants. With this assumption, the viscous damping coefficients can be expressed as
>
> $$ c_{ij}=c_{ij}\delta_{ij}=2\zeta_i \omega_i \delta_{ij} $$
>
> where $\zeta_i$ is called the damping ratio. Introducing this into the earlier equations, we obtain a set of uncoupled second-order ordinary differential equations:
>
> $$ \frac{d^2\eta_i}{dt^2} + 2\zeta_i \omega_i \frac{d\eta_i}{dt} + {\omega_i}^2 \eta_i = Q_i(t)$$

**Problem**: It's these last steps by Rao that I don't understand.  According to this assumed form for $C$, substituting this in we get $c(x) = \alpha_1 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left( EI(x) \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} \right) + \alpha_2 \rho A(x)$.  Then solving the problem as before, I get the following ODE:

$$ \frac{d^2\eta_i}{dt^2} + \left( \alpha_1 {\omega_i}^2 + \alpha_2 \right) \frac{d\eta_i}{dt} + {\omega_i}^2 \eta_i = Q_i(t) $$

The $d\eta_i / dt$ term is completely different, I don't see how that's supposed to become a $2\zeta_i \omega_i$, with $\zeta_i$ being some kind of damping ratio.  Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: The equations here seem to contain some typos and/or nonsense. What on earth is $c_{ij} = c_{ij}\delta_{ij}$ supposed to mean? If Rao is using the summation convention, $c_{ij}$ is a matrix but $c_{ij}\delta_{ij}$ is a scalar And if it doesn't use the summation convention, what is $\delta_{ij}$ - it doesn't seem to be a Kronecker delta.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem a little strange.  I think what Rao is saying in that equation is "first we have a different constant $c_{ij}$ for every combination of $i$ and $j$, but then we assume it's only nonzero for $i=j$ so we essentially only have $c_i$, and then we substitute the natural frequency * damping ratio for $c$" or something like that.